# Openpyxl - If a value in column F is true, grab the value in column A of the same row

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

As the topic says, I would like that if a value in column F is true, that it should grab the value in column A of the same row as the true value in column F.

This is what I got so far:

```
for row in ws['F1:F20']:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == True:
```

But I do not understand how to proceed with getting it to understand that it should grab the value in column A of the same row as the true value.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Use `cell.offset(column=-5)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in ws['F1:F20']:
  for cell in row:
    if cell.value is True:
      cell.offset(column=-5)
```